# Access Hash with multiple values ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a hash

```
h = Hash.new{|hsh,key| hsh[key] = [] }
```

And its values are stored as an array

Iv added to the value array for the key like so:

```
h[@name] << @age
h[@name] << @grade
```

and im trying to access the age like this

```
puts h[:@name][0]
```

But it doesn't work?

Is there a better way of doing this?

What im trying to do is create is a hash where there is a key which has loads of values:
For example `key=>name` and values equal `age`, `address`, `gender` etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*A Hash is a collection of key-value pairs like this: "employee" => "salary". It is similar to an Array, except that indexing is done via arbitrary keys of any object type, not an integer index.*

*The order in which you traverse a hash by either key or value may seem arbitrary and will generally not be in the insertion order. If you attempt to access a hash with a key that does not exist, the method will return nil.*

A hash is used to stored large (or small) amounts of data and access it efficiently. For example lets say you have this as a hash:

```
prices = {
  'orange' => 3.15,
  'apple' => 2.25,
  'pear' => 3.50
}
```

Now you want to call the keyword `apple` and get the prices of those items from some users input:

```
print 'Enter an item to verify price: '
item = gets.chomp

puts "The price of an #{item}: #{prices[item]}"
# <= The price of an apple: 2.25
```

That's a basic hash, now lets get into what you're doing, using an `Array` as a key.

```
prices = {
  'apple' => ['Granny Smith', 'Red'],
  'orange' => ['Good', 'Not good'],
  'pear' => ['Big', 'Small']
}

print 'Enter an item for a list: '
item = gets.chomp

puts "We have the following #{item}'s available: #{prices[item]}"
# <= We have the following apple's available: ["Granny Smith", "Red"]
```

Now if we wanted to grab one of the types:

```
puts prices[item][0]
# <= Granny Smith

puts prices[item][1]
#<= Red
```

Now lets get into more advanced techniques like you are doing above, you're idea is great and all, but what you need to do is append the information into the `hash` and when you call `@name` don't try to call it as a symbol:

```
h = Hash.new{|hsh,key| hsh[key] = [] }
h[@name] = []
#<= []

h[@name] << ['apple', 'pear']
#<= [["apple", "pear"]]
h[@name] << ['orange', 'apple']
#<= [["apple", "pear"], ["orange", "apple"]]

h[@name].flatten[0]
#<= "apple"
h[@name].flatten[1]
#<= "pear"
h[@name].flatten[1, 2]
#<= ["pear", "orange"]
```

Alright so what did we do?

```
h = Hash.new{|hsh,key| hsh[key] = [] }
```

Created a `hash` with a value as an empty `array`.

```
h[@name] = []
```

Initialized `@name` to the empty `array`

```
h[@name] << ['apple', 'pear']
```

Appended an array containing `apple, pear` to the `@name` key.

```
h[@name] << ['orange', 'apple']
```

Appended a second `array` containing `orange, apple` to the array, so when we call `h[@name][1]` right now it will output the first `array` appended to it.

```
h[@name].flatten[0]
```

Flattened the `array` into a single array and called the first element of the `array`.

When you call your key (`@name`) you don't call it as a symbol, because it's already contained inside of a variable. So all you have to do is call that variable and the value for that key will be output successfully. Hopefully this clarifies a few, things, for more information on `hashes` check this out: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_hashes.htm

Comment: Really appreciate the detailed answer

Answer (score 6):

IMHO your idea is ok.
The only mistake is.. how you access the hash. No need to add extra colon `:` before `@` sign.

Remove colon and it should work as you expect:

```
puts h[@name][0]
```