# How to access and map a Hash to minimum value when there are multiple values per key?

Tags: arrays, ruby, dictionary, hashmap

I'm looking to map an ID to the latest year.

If I have a hash which has one key to one value I don't have a problem:

```
hash = { 
  "123456"=>[["123456", "1975"], ["123456", "2009"]],
  "123999"=>[["123999", "1928"], ["123999", "2012"]] 
}

hash.map{|key, value| value.max}

# => [["123456", "2009"], ["123999", "2012"]]
```

I'm hoping to do the same but with the "value" having another element:

**Existing**

```
new_hash = { 
  "123456"=>[["123456", "1975", "ST"], ["123456", "2009", "PE"]],
  "123999"=>[["123999", "1928", "ST"], ["123999", "2012", "PE"]] 
}
```

Essentially again, what I'm looking to retrieve is the entry with the latest year, while keeping the third element, as below:

**Desired**

```
# => [["123456", "2009", "PE"], ["123999", "2012", "PE"]]
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: The closest query I found was: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661994/access-hash-with-multiple-values-ruby

However I still couldn't apply what's noted there to help me. Assuming the "value" is the array of three elements, I have tried `{|key, value| value[1].max}` however this just looks at the integer itself and can't apply `max` to it. Hopefully the idea of what I'm after is clear enough. If more info is needed, happy to provide.

Comment: Just provide(in the question) existing and desired data structures exactly.

Comment: Edited to further highlight the existing hash and the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`Enumerable#max_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by):

```rb
new_hash = { 
  "123456"=>[["123456", "1975", "ST"], ["123456", "2009", "PE"]],
  "123999"=>[["123999", "1928", "ST"], ["123999", "2012", "PE"]] 
}

new_hash.map { |_, array| array.max_by { |_, year,_| year } }

#=> [["123456", "2009", "PE"], ["123999", "2012", "PE"]]
```

Comment: That's done the trick! I had tried using the max_by method but I was using it all wrong. This is clear and understandable - thank you very much.